# Заготовить пищи и корма или заготовить пищу и корм?

Tags: синтаксис, морфология, падежи, управление, глаголы

- Заготовить пищи и корма или заготовить пищу и корм.

Вопрос по управлению глагола. Заготовить *что?* или *чего?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба варианта допустимы. Первый обычно употребляется при неопределённом объекте, второй — при определённом, но это нестрогое правило.